# onPause() gets called on my activity. Then, when brought back to the top, onResume() never gets called

Tags: android, android-activity

After the `onPause()` getting called, there are no calls to `onStop()` nor `onDestroy()`. The application is still running, and pid is the same (if I check it using "ps" Linux command). When the activity gets back on top, there are no calls to `onCreate()` nor `onResume()`. The app appears to be hanging. And after a while messages in the log appear saying "Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord". Oh, and it does not all the time. I can run it without getting stuck 2-3 times (with `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` called after `onPause()`, and the new activity getting created when it's time to get on top). But eventually I get the situation described in the title.

Any idea how this could happen? Many thanks :)

Comment: You need to post some relevant code for us to help. Are you doing network activity?

Comment: No network activity here. Mostly graphics.

Comment: Ok, you will still need to post some relevant code so we can see what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the app was actually hanging in the state "after `onPause()` called and complete",  waiting for a (not properly initialized) mutex while trying to handle an external event. The big part of the apps data was destroyed during `onPause()`, including that mutex.